# daily quote generator exceeding 1 year

Tags: mysql

dear stackoverflow member, 
I have constructed a quote database with a rapidly increasing number of quotes.

Sofar, as my quote number is < 366, I was able to show each day of the year a unique quote by using the following mysql query: 
    SELECT id, language, quote, owner FROM quote_of_the_day 
    where id=dayofyear(now())

Meanwhile my quote database has exceeded 450 quotes and I would like to have each remaining quote to be showed, even when the next year has started.
It should be something like 
    CASE WHEN count(*) < 366 THEN id=dayofyear(now() 
    ELSE id=dayofyear(now()+365

But I can't get it to work. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the modulus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all using a day of year as an identifier is probably not the best idea. You want to change your schema to either use dates instead of days of year as an or at least make it a composite id (year + day of the year).

Meanwhile you can use your conditional in the `WHERE` clause in the following way

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM quotes 
 WHERE id = CASE 
           WHEN (SELECT MAX(id) max_id FROM quotes) < 366
               THEN DAYOFYEAR(NOW())
           ELSE DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) + 365 
       END
```

which will work till the end of the year. Please find time until then to make appropriate schema changes.

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92276/7)** demo

Comment: thanks for both answers that have already helped me on the way. 
Now If I want to assure that all quotes get shown and that if the last quote is published, the next day the first quote will be shown, I will have to use something like: 
    CASE WHEN datediff <= count(*) THEN ID = datediff
ELSE ID = datediff - INT(datediff/count(*)) x count(*) END

Suppose datediff = 410 and number of quotes (count(*)) = 100,
this leads to ID = 410 - INT(410/100)x100, which is
ID = 410 - (4x100) = 10.

I am only struggling with a valid MYSQL query to get the abovementioned algorithm executed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who contributed. The belowmentioned MYSQL query does exactly what I want: Every day a next quote out of the list and when list end is reached, than  the next day nr. 1 quote of the list will be picked, etc.

```
SELECT id, language, quote, owner FROM quote_of_the_day
WHERE id=1+`datediff`(curdate(),'2012-12-01') mod (select count(*)
FROM quote_of_the_day)
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use `timestamp` fields for this instead of relying on the IDs - they can be messed up if you delete some records or add multiple quotes for some day. Then you could use an ordinary `WHERE` clause for this:

```
SELECT * FROM quotes
    WHERE (date_published BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND CURDATE())
    OR (date_published BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '06/06/2014')
    -- OR other clauses.
```

Hope this helps.